# How to store check box values in session when pagination is used

Tags: jsp

I have list of pagging 1 to 10. Say 10 records in each page. All the pagging have check box. If user checks first 2 records, am storing the value in session. And user click the second page and select 2 more records, the session value is overwrited. Can any body tell the solution?

My requirement is I have to store all the checked box value in session from first page and second page so on...but currently for me the last page checked value only storing in session.

Code

```
<form action="test.jsp" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="printPDF1" Value="Add to Cart"/>
<td><center>
<input type = "checkbox" name = "select" value = <%= searchObjNumber %> > 
</center></td>
```

In the second page(where i need to display all the selected values from the table):

```
<% String[] ids2=request.getParameterValues("select");

try { 

int q=0;

while(q < ids2.length) { %>

<span><input type="text" style="width:80%; border: 0px none;" id="text" value="Part number selected is <%=ids2[q]%>">

<% q++; } 

} %>
```

Comment: Post what you have tried !!!

Comment: Edit your question with code !! And also provide code for saving in session

Comment: Try some append operation before direct save

Comment: In the 1st page (i.e., the page which i select using check boxes)

<form action="test.jsp" name="test">
<input type="submit" name="printPDF1" Value="Add to Cart"/>

<td><center><input type = "checkbox" name = "select" value = <%= searchObjNumber %> ></center></td>

In the second page(where i need to display all the selected values from the table):

<%
 String[] ids2=request.getParameterValues("select");
 
try
{
 
 int q=0;
 while(q < ids2.length)
      {
 
%>
<span><input type="text" style="width:80%; border: 0px none;" id="text" value="Part number selected is <%=ids2[q]%>">  
<%
q++;
}
}

%>

Comment: try to store all array values to an ArrayList and save ArrayList in session